# How to get an attribute of parent of a table in sql stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to write a select stored procedure and in the where clause I want to check value of a field of the parent table of the curent table which I am performing the select query On , How can I acheive this ? 
any helps would be appreciated

Comment: Do you know the name of the parent table at design time?

Comment: @RobJohnson Consider Parent table as tblParent and chile table as tblChid

Comment: @downvoter care to comment ?

Comment: The question is very vague. You have omitted basic information such as table definitions.

Comment: @Karamafrooz http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html may be of use to you

Comment: @MartinSmith I don't think It's necessary To mention table names !

Comment: Well clearly three people disagree with you. The onus shouldn't be on the answerer to make up fictitious schema because you haven't supplied one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll nedd to `JOIN` those tables. Without knowing the tables definition, your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT C.*                   --- List the columns you want here 
FROM ChildTable C
INNER JOIN ParentTable P
    ON C.ParentID = P.ID     --- something along this lines
WHERE P.SomeField = 1        --- put here your condition on the parent table
```

Comment: thanks a lot I got what to do :)